# Force height of <div> to match image

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm building a responsive page that has an image and `<div>` side by side:

[image]

The width and height of the image retain their proportions and expand/contract with the browser window.

The width of the `<div>` does the same, but I'd like it to match the image in terms of height.

Is there any way of achieving this? Here's a Fiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/xwJHw/

Comment: Wrap the both in a div, and add height of text box to 100%.

Comment: Might help: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Comment: You could, if you wrap the DIV around the IMG… in any other case you need to fake that behavior (e.g. by following the ideas from the link biziclop has posted) or by utilizing JavaScript to set both boxes to equal heights.

Comment: Fiddle of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/xwJHw/

Comment: @feeela: And what about the pure css solution mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @A.K your solution is essentially faux columns, which won't do in my scenario unfortunately. There are multiple elements under these two at the top, and the elements must be floated like in my Fiddle.

Comment: @A.K. as alecrust said that's the faux columns solution – or as I called the fake-solution ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **display:table** property for this. Write like this:

```
section{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.text-box,.image{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xwJHw/8/

Note: **display:table** works till IE8 & above.

Comment: Thanks for this, the elements need to be floated though I'm afraid due to other limitations of the responsive page.

Comment: @alecrust using `display: table;` is an alternative to floating elements. Think about your goal and don't be so narrow-minded. Do you have a real good reason to float the elements by any means, even if the desired layout could be achieved in another way? Or do you need support for IE 7?

Comment: I do need support for IE7, but I'm happy to get around that separately. I did try to achieve this layout with this method originally but it became unwieldy and caused many other issues. Will continue to have a play, thanks for your narrow-minded comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery.

Calculate the hight of the image using $('#imgId').height() and the set the same to Div.

Also see the code, how heights are adjusted here http://filamentgroup.com/examples/equalHeights/

Comment: Thanks for that. Any way without JavaScript? Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/xwJHw/

Comment: Is this jQuery solution fluid? The Filament Group example is not.

Comment: @alecrust: This is a fine solution and also implemented in your fiddle, see here: jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/xwJHw/6

Comment: Interesting solution! It's essentially faux columns though, which won't do in my scenario unfortunately. There are multiple elements under these two at the top, and the elements must be floated like in my Fiddle.

Comment: @alecrust This is not faux columns as you are not coloring the background of some wrapper but set the definite height of all the boxes.

Comment: @feeela I was talking about the solution posted in this comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

**@alecrust:** This is a fine solution and also implemented in your fiddle, [**See Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/xwJHw/6)

A pure css solution: [**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/EbxkX/)

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}

.placeholder_image {
    float: left;
    width: 430px;
    height: 264px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;   
}

.placeholder_text {
    background: #ccc;
    margin-left: 450px;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="placeholder_image">
        <img src="http://www.qesign.com/templates/designs/christmas-after-effects-animated-e-card-template-31966.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="placeholder_text">
        A block of text
    </div>
</div>
```

​

​

Comment: This solution is not fluid. If we're dealing with fixed widths and heights this is easy. See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/xwJHw/

Comment: @alecrust: This is a fine solution and also implemented in your fiddle, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/xwJHw/6/

Comment: Interesting solution! It's essentially faux columns though, which won't do in my scenario unfortunately. There are multiple elements under these two at the top, and the elements must be floated like in my Fiddle.

Comment: @ alecrust: o.k I got it, but I don't understand why this down vote? I was trying to help.

Comment: Apologies. From my understanding you're supposed to downvote if the answer isn't helpful. Your edited version is though, I have removed the downvote.